# Deleting millions of record in bunch in postgresql

Tags: sql, sql-delete, postgresql-9.1, bulk

I have to delete rows from table that has 120 millions records.
The data that has highest(entry_date) and second highest(entry_date) should not be deleted.

Table has many constraints.
One PRIMARY key
Two FOREIGN keys
and two indexes other than index on primary key.

I have already successfully tried method to delete as creating temp table and moving required data into temp table.
Then dropping the present table and then again moving back filtered data from temp to main table.And it worked fine.
But I need a way to delete records in bunch .

```
CREATE TABLE values
(
  value_id bigint NOT NULL,
  content_definition_id bigint NOT NULL,
  value_s text,
  value_n double precision,
  order integer,
  scope_id integer NOT NULL,
  answer boolean NOT NULL,
  date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  entry_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "value_PK" PRIMARY KEY (value_id),
  CONSTRAINT content_definition_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (content_definition_id)
      REFERENCES content_definition (content_definition_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT scope_fk FOREIGN KEY (scope_id)
      REFERENCES scopes (scope_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
-- Index: fki_content_definition_id_fk
-- Index: fki_value_value_scope_id
```

How to delete record in bunch like first only 1 million data should be deleted and on.

Comment: Can we disable index and constraint and try deleting after that.If so can any body please tell me the syntax of temporary disabling index and foreign key in postgres.

Comment: Add table definition, and some sample table data.

Comment: full table definition added ..

Comment: Please, translate your crore and lakhs to some more common units.

Comment: `The data that has heighest(entry_date) and second heighest(entry_date) should not be deleted.` So: keep the two most recent items. Two items per *what* ? {content_id, scope_id} ?

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you have no conflicting locks.  Note that index page locks may slow things down as well.

Recent PostgreSQL allows you to use a CTE in a delete statement.  I.e. you can:

```
WITH ids_to_delete (
    SELECT value_id FROM values
    where ...
    limit ...
)
delete from values where value_id in (select value_id from ids_to_delete)
```

Comment: Is there any way to disable foreign key constraint temporarily and after delete enable ??

Answer (score 0):

Can you try merge with conditions of your temp tables and use delete part of it. That should give you a good performance